# POEDIT- Show Error: a format specification for argument 1 doesn't exist in 'msgstr'

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I have a the code follow to write in `functions.php` of WordPress theme:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('mytheme_entry_meta')){
    function mytheme_entry_meta(){
        if(!is_page()){
        ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php printf(__('<span class="author">Posted by %1$s</span>', 'mytheme'), get_the_author()); ?>
                <?php printf(__('<span class="date-pulished">at %1$s</span>', 'mytheme'), get_the_date()); ?>
                <?php printf(__('<span class="category">in %1$s</span>', 'mytheme'), get_the_category_list(',')); ?>
                <?php if(comments_open()){ ?>
                <span class="meta-reply">
                    <?php comments_popup_link(
                        __('Leave a comment','mytheme'),
                        __('One comment','mytheme'),
                        __('% comments','mytheme'),
                        __('Read all comments','mytheme')
                    ); ?>
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

After I use POEDIT application to translate to Vietnamese language. But POEDIT show

`Error: a format specification for argument 1 doesn't exist in 'msgstr'`

And position error in `% comments`. Please see 2 below images:

- **Image 1**: The position show error
  [The position show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rhxA.png)
- **Image 2**: After I click Save button, show message error.
  [After I click Save button, show message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FVJK.png)

Answer (score 3):

First, you translated the string badly and omitted `%` from the source. Second, your PO file [incorrectly marks the string as being `php-format` while it isn’t](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/poedit/f34rrvx7UT8/vjaWHOK2O1QJ), which you have to fix in your code [like this](https://github.com/osclass/Osclass/commit/679f19a064808d46c14c199bf4c36531e9b5993d):

```
/* xgettext:no-php-format */
__('% comments','mytheme'),
```

Comment: Can I understand your mean that I must convert `%` character into ASCII code (`%` -> `&#37;`) ?

Comment: No, not at all, I don’t see how you jumped to *that* conclusion. I mean what I wrote above (including the example code!). If it’s unclear, you should read both of the links I provided you, they explain everything.